# $\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{H_n(x)H_n(y)t^n}{2^nn!}$=$\frac{\exp\left[\frac{2xyt-(x^2+y^2)t^2}{1-t^2}\right]}{\sqrt{1-t^2}}$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, functions, special-functions, hermite-polynomials

I am told to prove that :

> $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{H_n(x)H_n(y)t^n}{2^nn!} = \frac{\exp\left[\frac{2xyt-(x^2+y^2)t^2}{1-t^2}\right]}{\sqrt{1-t^2}}$$

where $H_n(x)$ is Hermite polynomial.I am wondering how to prove it.please help me how to prove this.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** Try to use the generating function for Hermite polynomials, given by 
$$\exp(2xt-t^2) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} H_n(x) \frac{t^n}{n!}$$

**EDIT**:

As suggested by OP, I am posting the [link](https://sci-hub.tw/https://doi.org/10.1088/1674-1056/24/5/050303) to the solution here.The full derivation is mentioned there with the final expression in Eq. 18 with the simple substitution $t \to \frac{t}{2}$ in that equation to obtain the result here.

Comment: Can you explain me little bit more?I am unable to progress.

Comment: Think about expressing the LHS of what you have to prove using the RHS of what I have stated.

Comment: Is there any relation for product of Hermite polynomials?

Comment: I am unable handle this product $H_n(x)H_n(y)$

Comment: Should is have to use any result of series here?

Comment: Why don;t you multiply the series in RHS with the same series, one with variable $x$ and the other with $y$? And see how the LHS changes.

Comment: How will I handle the product of two infinite series?

Comment: Like you handle the product of two infinite sums. Try to manipulate the terms and see if you can try to reach the LHS of your expression. The aim is to make you understand the working of the problem by making you try solve the problem. If you can't, then I will post a complete solution.

Comment: Better you post a complete solution

Comment: Still waiting for answer,I tried my best but didn't reach conclusion

Comment: @lbs Actually I got a little busy today. Didn't have enough time to write a full solution. However, I have attached a paper. With proper comments. Look through that. I hope it will help.

Comment: yes I got the paper and it is really helpful,thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3):

Use the generating function given in a previous answer.  Use the integral

$$ H_n(y) = \frac{2^{n/2}}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \int_{-\infty}^\infty (y\sqrt{2}+i\,u)^n \exp{(-u^2/2)} \, du $$

(This appears on the wiki for Hermite polynomials, but I've converted it to physicist notation.) Then

$$ \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(t/2)^n}{n!}H_n(x)\,H_n(y) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}
\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-u^2/2} \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{H_n(x)}{n!} \big(\frac{t}{\sqrt{2}}(y\sqrt{2} + iu)\big)^n  = $$
$$=  \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-u^2/2} 
\exp{\big(2x(t\,y+it\,u/\sqrt{2}) - t^2/2(y\sqrt{2}+iu)^2 } \big)$$
where in the last step the generating function was used.  Collect the coefficients of $u$ in the exponential argument.  The constant term in front of the integral is $\exp{(2\,t\,x\,y - t^2\,y^2)}.$  Now use the well-known formula
$$ \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^\infty \exp\big({-a\,u^2/2 + \sqrt{2}\,i\,b\,u}\big)\,du  = \exp{\big(-b^2/a\big)}$$
where $a=1-t^2$ and $b=t(x-t\,y).$  Algebra completes the proof.

Comment: Nice approach....